# How to connect Kotlin Coroutines in LibGDX?

Tags: libgdx

At the moment, the latest version of Kotlin coroutines: **'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.2'**

Answer (score 0):

### build.gradle (App):

---

### Desctop:

```
project(":desktop") {
apply plugin: "java-library"
dependencies {
    implementation project(":core")
    api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
    api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
  
    // Kotlin Coroutines / Flow
    def kotlinCoroutinesFlow = "1.5.2"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines- 
    core:$kotlinCoroutinesFlow"
    }
 }
```

---

### Core:

```
project(":core") {
apply plugin: "java-library"
dependencies {
    api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
 
    // Kotlin Coroutines / Flow
    def kotlinCoroutinesFlow = "1.5.2"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$kotlinCoroutinesFlow"
    }
}
```

---

### Android:

```
project(":android") {
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
configurations { natives }
dependencies {
    implementation project(":core")
    api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
   
    // Kotlin Coroutines / Flow
    def kotlinCoroutinesFlow = "1.5.2"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$kotlinCoroutinesFlow"
    }
}
```

---

### iOS:

```
project(":ios") {
apply plugin: "java-library"
apply plugin: "robovm"
dependencies {
    implementation project(":core")
    api "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-rt:$roboVMVersion"
    api "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-cocoatouch:$roboVMVersion"
    api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-robovm:$gdxVersion"
    api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
   
    // Kotlin Coroutines / Flow
    def kotlinCoroutinesFlow = "1.5.2"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$kotlinCoroutinesFlow"
    }
}
```